# Можно ли узнать количество кликов или нажатий мыши по canvas в JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Можно ли узнать количество кликов или нажатий мыши по canvas в JS? Реально ли это?

Comment: можно, реально 
$(function(){
      canvas.addEventListener('click', function() { // считаем тут клики
      }, false);
});

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, небольшой пример:

```js
var canv = document.getElementById("canv");
var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
var count = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
$('.count').html("Количество нажатий: " + count)
$('#canv').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  count++
  $('.count').html("Количество нажатий: " + count)
});
```

```css
#canv:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canv">
</canvas>
<div class="count">
</div>
```

Comment: Недавно наткнулся на такую штуку, как Trusted Events. Если в браузере есть поддержка, то у объекта события будет свойство event.isTrusted. Оно гарантирует, что событие было вызвано пользователем, а не, к примеру trigger('click'); Можно добавить это в обработчик, чтобы знать что это пользователь.